# the heck of me... I still can't get the value of radio button to display - Javascript dom

Tags: javascript

I still can't get the value of the radio button to display on the 2nd html summary page. I've researched and researched and changed the javascript function but have no even come close. What is the answer to make it work. I need someone to change my code and I can see where I went wrong :(

The form:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="get" action="summary.html">

            <label for="firstname">First Name:</label><input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" autofocus placeholder="John" required="required" maxlength="15" />
            <br>
            <label for="surname">Surname:</label><input id="surname" name="surname" type="text" placeholder="Smith" required="required" maxlength="30" />
            <br>
            <br>           
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" id="radio1"/><label for="male">Male</label>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" id="radio2" checked="checked"/><label for="female">Female</label>         
            <br>
            <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Register" />
            <br>    
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The Summary Answers;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="JavaScript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>         
            <td id="firstname" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="surname" /></td>
        </tr>      
        <tr>
            <td id="gender" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

The js.

```
    window.onload = function () {
   "use strict";

   var url = new URL(window.location.href);

   var firstname = url.searchParams.get("firstname"); document.getElementById("firstname").innerText = firstname;

    var surname = url.searchParams.get("surname"); document.getElementById("surname").innerText = surname;

    //var radios = document.getElementsByName('gender');
    //for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
       // if (radios[i].checked) {
            //innerText = radios;               
          //  break;
      ///  }
    //}

};
```

added the last thing I tried as comments.

Comment: When you submit the form, the browser will determine which radio button is selected, and put that value (either Male or Female) into the querystring, just like it did for firstname and surname. You should just be able to follow suit with how you did the other two in the JavaScript, only using "gender" as the parameter name. The commented JS you show won’t work because the summary answers page doesn’t have any elements with a name of gender (those were on the previous page).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your radio input follows the same pattern as your other inputs, so looks like you are just not collecting it.

```
  var gender = url.searchParams.get('gender');
  document.getElementById('gender').innerText = gender;
```